# Constructor overloading issue in java

Tags: java

I am learing core java and practicing it. I understand the concept of method overloading. But when I run the below program it shows error as "

```
constructor Methodover in class Methodover cannot be applied to given types;
        Methodover m2 = new Methodover();
                        ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"
```

Please find my code below and help.. I am just learning.

```
public class Methodover
{   
    int x;
    int y;

     Methodover(int a, int b)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
        System.out.println("The values assigned are" +x+ "And" +y);

    }

    void multiply(Methodover obj)
    {   obj.x = 2;
        obj.y = 2;
        System.out.println("The multiplication result with object passed is" +obj.x*obj.y );

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Methodover m1 = new Methodover(5,6);
        Methodover m2 = new Methodover();
        m2.multiply(m1);

    }

}
```

Comment: You only have one constructor, which expects two `int` arguments. To call it like you have, you need to add a default constructor like `Methodover() { x = 0; y = 0; }`

Comment: yes.. That worked. But I quite dont understand why do we need that. When I am creating an object with two params the constructor with the 2 arguments will be invoked. But when I create another object without any params passed, no non-parametrized constructor is not present, then when it throws error on the second object creation line. The concept is same as contructor overloading right?

Comment: What yoy have said is to define a non-parameterized constructor. But when I dont need to invoke such a constructor why do I need to declare that

Comment: Because you **are** invoking one: the call `Methodover m2 = new Methodover();` is invoking a constructor taking no arguments.

Comment: Methodover m2 = new Methodover(); is just creating an object right? When there is any constructor without any arguments defined in the program then only it would invoke that function. Otherwise it would just simply create a object of that class right? I understand this from the method overloading concept. The particular method is detected based on no of parameters passed/type of params

Comment: If you had a method `multiply(int a, int b)` and you called it as `multiply()`, it wouldn't work, because you didn't supply an `a` or a `b`. Same thing with constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while playing with constructor, always use default constructor to avoid run time Exceptions.define default constructor in your code..

```
 Methodover()
 {
      //initialize default values.
      this(0, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a no-argument (parameter less) contructor in your class, that is why you are getting the error. By default a class is provided with no-argument  constructor, since you provided your own constructor which takes two parameters, you can't use the default constructor any more. Define a defult constructor, or call the one you have.

```
public class Methodover
{   
    int x;
    int y;

     Methodover() //new no-argument (parameter less) constructor
     {
     } 

     Methodover(int a, int b)
    {
        x=a;
        y=b;
        System.out.println("The values assigned are" +x+ "And" +y);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no zero argument constructor in this class. Whenever you write your constructor then JVM do not provide default constructor.

JVM provide the No argument constructor when you do not have any constructor in the class.

As from your class you have two argument constructor and you are calling zero argument constructor.

To solve this write zero argument constructor also.

```
Methodover() {
  //Zero Argument Constructor or No Argument constructor.
}

Methodover(int a, int b) {
    x=a;
    y=b;
    System.out.println("The values assigned are" +x+ "And" +y);
}
```

This is called constructor overloading.

Answer (score 1):

I java if you define your own constructor with parameter.

then you can't use default constructor(without parameter) without defining it.

to use it you have to define it manually

here use are using default constructor for m2 . .  and you have not defined it

Answer (score 1):

Create Default Constructor in class Methodover

```
   Methodover()
   { }
```

Error is because you have parametirized constructor with two parameters

OR you can create object like below

```
   Methodover m2 = new Methodover(2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default (zero argument) constructor is like a lawyer that represents you in the court. If you don't have one - JVM will provide it for you, but if you have one - the default won't be there :-) (I took this metaphor from [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208), a great book for any beginner in Java language and OOP)

Answer (score 1):

By default every custom class created in Java will have parameter-less constructor.

Now if you define a constructor which takes parameters

```
public  Methodover(int a, int b)
{
        x=a;
        y=b;
        System.out.println("The values assigned are" +x+ "And" +y);

}
```

and **do not** define a default constructor explicitly like below

```
public Methodover()
{

}
```

Java will take that, the **only way** of **constructing** the object of your class is via the **ONLY parameterised constructor** you have created.

*Hence, the error you are getting. To fix this, explicitly define a default constructor, as explained in other answers*

**Why Java takes away the default constructor when you dont explicity define it along with other parameterised constructors?**

Consider [immutable design pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29), here we restrict the user to supply the value for the object while its being constructed. If Java would have allowed the default constructor, then there was no way of restricting the user to pass the value for the object while they are being created.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the doubt. Now I am very clear on that.. I thought that the constructor would be invoked (while object creation )only when there is one otherwise it would simply create a object. I was not knowing the fact that whenever you try to create an object without any constructor defined in the program, then JVM would provide a default non-parameterised constructor for us without defining manually by us. So for every program where we create custom class a non parameterised default contructor is required (which JVM would provide automatically if we have not defined)

Answer (score -1):

You created object for default constructor

`Methodover m2 = new Methodover();`

but you did not define the default constructor.

Comment: downvote by me, as this thread is from 2013 and your answer don't add any new information.